# Selenium Webdriver Chromedriver timeout on start in headless mode

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver, with Ruby 32-bit 1.9.3, Chromedriver v2.9.248315, Chrome 38.0.2125.111 m and a local instance of Jenkins 1.588

Gems: cucumber (1.3.17), selenium-webdriver (2.43.0), watir-webdriver (0.6.11) (can provide list of all others if you think necessary)

Windows 7 Professional 64-bit edition.

When running a Jenkins job which starts Chrome using chromedriver and then trying to interact with it I get a timeout error. When doing the same on my desktop via a command prompt window it works perfectly. Running the same Jenkins job, starting Firefox instead of Chrome it works perfectly.

Simple example (C:\test.rb):

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
$browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :http_client => client
$browser.driver.manage.window.maximize
$browser.close
```

Jenkins job configured to run Windows Batch Command:

```
cd \
ruby test.rb
```

The output when I run the job:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\test chromedriver\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson3963234995624341455.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\test chromedriver\workspace>cd \ 

C:\>ruby test.rb 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill': Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rbuf_fill'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2563:in `read_status_line'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2552:in `read_new'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1320:in `block in transport_request'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1317:in `catch'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1317:in `transport_request'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1294:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1287:in `block in request'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:746:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1285:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83:in `response_for'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:638:in `raw_execute'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:616:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:236:in `maximizeWindow'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/window.rb:98:in `maximize'
    from test.rb:5:in `<main>'

C:\>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have tried enabling "Allow service to interact with desktop" in the Jenkins service, then watching the window (in a more complex scenario) and the Chrome window opens, but does nothing. I originally had the problem with "$browser.cookies.clear" and after commenting out that line I now have the same problem with the line $browser.driver.manage.window.maximize

I was running complex cucumber scenarios with no trouble using Chromedriver. Then I had my PC rebuilt and after installing Jenkins, Ruby, Chromedriver (adding both to PATH) and copying the old jobs into my new Jenkins installation I had the above problem. I then created the simple example above, tested it and created this post.

If anyone has any ideas about how I can get Chromedriver working again that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome 38 does not work when running as system user in Session 0.  Normally this occurs because Chrome is launched by a Windows service - in your case Jenkins which is run as a service.  This is a known issue.  See Selenium issues [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8034&noredir=1) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=928).

Two solutions:

1. Downgrade Chrome to a version less than 38.
2. Download and install [AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/) and [configure it to run your Jenkins service as a user other than default system user](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/AlwaysUp_FAQ.html#AvoidSession0)

The AlwaysUp solution definitely works but has a small licencing cost, or if you're not bothered about the Chrome version you can downgrade it.

Comment: I've just tried 3. changed the user in the services entry for Jenkins, I added in a whoami to the script to confirm that it is now using the different user (it is). I still get exactly the same error. I have got Chrome 38, so I'll try downgrading Chrome version

Comment: updated answer to remove the option that didn't work

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to downgrade Chrome, all the legitimate-looking downloads I could find redirected me to the Google Chrome download page, which forces me to download the latest version of Chrome. It does, however, look like they're going to fix it in Chrome 39 https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=422218

Answer (score 1):

Chrome cannot run in headless mode in windows.
you need to use HTMLdriver for this.

If you badly needs it, you need to try setup a vnc server and run within it.
http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/

Comment: I don't know if "headless mode" is the right word for what I'm trying to do, but it does work, it worked on my machine before it was rebuilt, it works on another server and on another person's machine. Jenkins starts up an instance of Chrome on a "virtual desktop" and should then run the test, but it's not on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by SDET helped me (upvoted), Session 0 was my problem, but you don't need AlwaysUp, you can just launch the jenkins slave from some startup script by: `javaws http://<jenkins-master>/computer/<node-name>/slave-agent.jnlp`