# Chrome browser not launching through jenkins user in jenkins

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

[image: As shown in the image I'm copying the project to jenkins workspace]

[image: the goal is only clean install]

But this does not launch chrome browser. It just shows below output and keeps loading
[image]

The same thing works if I execute a shell command "sudo mvn clean install".
But it does not work if I specify goals and options.

This looks like jenkins user is not authorized to launch chrome. 
Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: do a chown on Chrome and see who owns it

Comment: Chrome is owned by jenkins user but still facing the same issue.

Comment: The application which you run in jenkins in the one starting chrome right ?? and you mentioned that `I execute a shell command "sudo mvn clean install"` this is done in your local and not in jenkins right ??

Comment: While performing 'sudo mvn clean install' from the shell , the browser launches through jenkins in my local but it does not happen if specified through the goals and options.

Comment: Have you selected the `Run Headless` option ?? in advance ... Also Does it timeout??

Comment: No I haven't selected the 'Run Headless' option. It does timeout after a few minutes since the browser does not open.

Comment: have you tried this http://blog.dougdragon.com/what-is-jenkins-doing/ ??

Comment: yes tried that as well. :(

Comment: looks like a driver issue... you will have to downgrade your chrome....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737311/selenium-webdriver-chromedriver-timeout-on-start-in-headless-mode